# WP7 - InvalidOperationException while playing sound

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using System.IO;

Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/BEEP.WAV");
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

I get InvalidOperationException in line "SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream)"
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx), the file pointed to by stream has very specific requirements:

```
The Stream object must point to the head of a valid PCM wave file. Also, this wave file must be in the RIFF bitstream format.

The audio format has the following restrictions:

    Must be a PCM wave file
    Can only be mono or stereo
    Must be 8 or 16 bit
    Sample rate must be between 8,000 Hz and 48,000 Hz
```